# Faster method of accessing a channel from RGB image in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

In my trials with images of 1409x900 and 960x696, it takes 2.5 ms on average to split channels of a RGB image using OpenCV in my 64-bit 6-core 3.2 GHz Windows machine.

```
vector<cv::Mat> channels;
cv::split(img, channels);
```

I found that this is almost similar amount of time for the other image processing (boolean operation + morphological opening).

Considering my code only uses an image of a channel from the splitting, I wonder if there is any faster way of extracting single channel from a RGB image, preferably with OpenCV.

**UPDATE**

As @DanMašek pointed out, there was another function mixChannels that can extract a single channel image from multi-channel. I've tested about 2000 images with the same sizes. mixChannels took about 1 ms on average. For now, I am satisfied with the result. But post your answer if you can make it faster.

```
cv::Mat channel(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1);
int from_to[] = { sel_channel,0 };
mixChannels(&img, 1, &channel, 1, from_to, 1);
```

Comment: So, you're interested in just one of the 3 channels? (since you say "an image of a channel") | Do you do the split repeatedly?

Comment: @DanMašek Yes, I just need one channel among 3 and I do it repeatedly with images from a 200-FPS camera.

Comment: Ok. For one, allocating a new `cv::Mat` does carry an overhead. In my experience it's beneficial to reuse already allocated `Mat`s when possible. As you only need one channel, I'd try one of the [`cv::mixChannels` overloads](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga51d768c270a1cdd3497255017c4504be).

Comment: In general, separating the channels will be more expensive than simple arithmetic or logical operations, it's somewhat tricky to vectorize that (and groups of 3 values don't make it easier). I haven't really looked much into the implementation of those two OpenCV functions, but if this is a bottleneck, it may be worth writing your own custom version for this specific scenario using SIMD intrinsics (especially if you only need to support very small subset of platforms).

Comment: And in an attempt at a bit of an out-of-the box thinking... does the camera support returning Bayer CFA image (single channel, before demosaicing), rather than RGB, and do you happen to be interested in the green channel? If that was the case, you'd just need the first stage of the demosaicing, which reconstructs the green plane...

Comment: @DanMašek To answer your question, in my code, user selects a channel and thus I can't decide which channel to use. But once it's decided, program will use only that channel. Thanks for your answers. I will try your suggestion. I recommend you post your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two simple options come to mind here.

1. You mention that you perform this operation repeatedly on images captured from a camera. Therefore it is safe to assume that the images are always the same size.

   Allocations of `cv::Mat` have a non-negligible overhead, so in this case it would be beneficial to reuse the channel `Mat`s. (i.e. allocate the destination images when you receive the first frame, and then just overwrite the contents for subsequent frames)

   The additional benefit of this approach is (quite likely) reducing memory fragmentation. This can become a real problem for 32bit code.
2. You mention that you're interested in only one specific channel (which the user may select arbitrarily). That means you could use [`cv::mixChannels`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga51d768c270a1cdd3497255017c4504be), which gives you the flexibility in selecting what channels and how you want to extract them.

   That means you can extract data for only a single channel, theoretically (depending on the implementation -- study the source code for more details) avoiding the overhead in extracting and/or copying the data for the channels you're not interested in.

---

Let's make a test program evaluating the 4 possible combinations of the approaches outlined above.

- Variant 0: `cv::split` without reuse
- Variant 1: `cv::split` with reuse
- Variant 2: `cv::mixChannels` without reuse
- Variant 3: `cv::mixChannels` with reuse

NB: I just use `static` for simplicity here, usually i'd make this member variable in a class that wraps the algorithm.

---

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define SELECTED_CHANNEL 1

cv::Mat variant_0(cv::Mat const& img)
{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
    cv::split(img, channels);
    return channels[SELECTED_CHANNEL];
}

cv::Mat variant_1(cv::Mat const& img)
{
    static std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
    cv::split(img, channels);
    return channels[SELECTED_CHANNEL];
}

cv::Mat variant_2(cv::Mat const& img)
{
    // NB: output Mat must be preallocated
    cv::Mat channel(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1);
    int from_to[] = { SELECTED_CHANNEL, 0 };
    cv::mixChannels(&img, 1, &channel, 1, from_to, 1);
    return channel;
}

cv::Mat variant_3(cv::Mat const& img)
{
    // NB: output Mat must be preallocated
    static cv::Mat channel(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1);
    int from_to[] = { SELECTED_CHANNEL, 0 };
    cv::mixChannels(&img, 1, &channel, 1, from_to, 1);
    return channel;
}

template<typename T>
void timeit(std::string const& title, T f)
{
    using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::microseconds;

    cv::Mat img(1024,1024, CV_8UC3);
    cv::randu(img, 0, 256);

    int32_t const STEPS(1024);

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (uint32_t i(0); i < STEPS; ++i) {
        cv::Mat result = f(img);
    }
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    double t_ms(static_cast<double>(duration) / 1000.0);
    std::cout << title << "\n"
        << "Total = " << t_ms << " ms\n"
        << "Iteration = " << (t_ms / STEPS) << " ms\n"
        << "FPS = " << (STEPS / t_ms * 1000.0) << "\n"
        << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    for (uint8_t i(0); i < 2; ++i) {
        timeit("Variant 0", variant_0);
        timeit("Variant 1", variant_1);
        timeit("Variant 2", variant_2);
        timeit("Variant 3", variant_3);
        std::cout << "--------------------------\n\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Output for the second pass (so we avoid any warmup costs).

Note: Running this on i7-4930K, using OpenCV 3.1.0 (64-bit, MSVC12.0), Windows 10 -- YMMV, especially with CPUs that have AVX2

```
Variant 0
Total = 1518.69 ms
Iteration = 1.48309 ms
FPS = 674.267

Variant 1
Total = 359.048 ms
Iteration = 0.350633 ms
FPS = 2851.99

Variant 2
Total = 820.223 ms
Iteration = 0.800999 ms
FPS = 1248.44

Variant 3
Total = 427.089 ms
Iteration = 0.417079 ms
FPS = 2397.63
```

---

Interestingly, `cv::split` with reuse wins here. Feel free to edit the answer and add timings from different platforms/CPU generations (especially if the proportions differ radically).

It also seems that with my setup, none of this is parallelized quite well, so that may be another possible path at speeding this up (something like `cv::parallel_for_`).

Comment: Wouldn't be faster to use a `cv::UMat` instead ?

Comment: @karlphillip Worth a try. Depends on whether OP can do the rest of the processing on GPU as well. My intuition (and I may be talking outta my ass here, as I haven't played with that yet) says that just for this the overhead of moving the data may be too large. I'll play with it later, it's getting a bit late.